# Trying to round a string that has a comma in it [python]

Tags: python, string

I am making a price ticker for reddit. Everything is working fine, but the API that it derives the price from has 4 decimal places, and a comma in it dividing the thousands.

I am just trying to figure out how to round the number to either 2 decimals, or a whole number. So far I have tried the round() function, which does not work because of the comma. I was able to remove the comma, but it still won't let me use the round function.

```
def main(self):
    req = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
    req = req.json()
    dollar = '1 BTC = $' + req['bpi']['USD']['rate'].replace(',' , '')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did... did you convert the string to a number before calling `round` on it?

Comment: Please show us how you tried to use the round function--your given code does not attempt this. And do you want your final value for `dollar` to be a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should usually use the Decimal class in python when playing with numbers like this-

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> t = '4,700.3245'
>>> Decimal(t.replace(',', '')).quantize(Decimal('1.00'))
Decimal('4700.32')
```

quantize is the "round" function for Decimal objects- it will round to the same number of decimal places as the Decimal object passed as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could point you in the right direction!

```
# Original String
val_string = '19,9999'

# Replace Comma with Decimal
val_string_decimal = val_string.replace(',','.')

# Convert String to Float
val = float(val_string_decimal)

# Print Float after rounding to 2 decimal places
print(round(val, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify whether you want to re-insert the comma after rounding. Try this:

```
# dummy number
str_num = "4,000.8675"
# first, remove the comma
str_num_no_comma = str_num.replace(",","")
# then, convert to float, and then round
strm_num_as_num = round(float((str_num_no_comma)))
print(strm_num_as_num)
>>> 4001.0
```

Of course you can cast as `int` if you want to ignore decimal points entirely.